# GSON : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING

Tags: java, json, gson

I am facing a problem about the GSON json to Java. I looked up many posts here, but I cannot find the solution for my question. So I list my problem here. Thanks very much !

Here is my Json Data

```
"{
    "data": {
        "marks": "",
        "spines": "",
        "dendrites": {
            "voxel": [
                [383,382,382,381],
                [49,50,51,52],
                [7,10,10,10],
                [0,0,0,0]
            ],
            "maxint": [32,42,28,28],
            "maxintcorrected": null,
            "maxintcube": null,
            "medianfiltered": [54.36979745,54.36979745,54.36979745,54.36979745],
            "meanbacksingle": null,
            "maxintsingle": null,
            "thres": null,
            "meanback": 42,
            "index": 1,
            "length": [0,0.3223757885,0.6336712814,0.9350672197,1.227262867],
            "XYlength": [0,0.2085982964,0.410997367,0.6084466603]
        }
    }
}
"
```

My Class's defination is following

```
public class Test {
    public data data;

    public class data {

        public Object marks;
        public String spines = "";
        public StandardSpinenalysisImage.data.dendrites[] dendrites;

        public class dendrites {

            public int voxel[][];
            public int maxint[];
            public String maxintcorrected = "";
            public String maxintcube = "";
            public int medianfiltered[];
            public String meanbacksingle = "";
            public String maxintsingle = "";
            public int thres = 0;
            public int meanback;
            public int index = 0;
            public int length[];
            public int XYlength[];

            public dendrites() {
                this.thres = 100;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I use the code 
    Test t = g.fromJson(input, Test.class);

I got the error result.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 5
```

Thank you very very MUCH!!

Comment: Is there a reason why "marks" is of type "Object" while everything else is of type "String"?

Comment: Why do you have '"' at the beggining and end of your json file ?

Comment: @JasonSperske I just test it ... I think marks also is a type of string here. Just test

Comment: @giorashc. Hi, THANKS. I just copy it from the debug mode. It said Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 5. Where is the problem? Thanks

Comment: Class names in Java should start with Capital letter: wrong: public class dendrites good: public class Dendrites

Answer (score 2):

your json looks good. just try remove the " from the beginning and the end of the json

you can try using [this link](http://jsonformat.com/) to verify your json

Comment: The JSOn is fine. " is used to tell its a string..

String json= "that above json";

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same error today. In mine, the problem was one variable in JSON mapped to a String, but in the class the variable was on object of a Class Type. This made Gson think that the JSON variable should be of the Class Type, causing IllegalStateException with `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING`

Hope it helps someone.